# How to print out a specific field in AWK?

Tags: awk, filtering

A very simple question, which a found no answer to. How do I print out a specific field in awk?

`awk '/word1/'`, will print out the whole sentence, when I need just a `word1`. Or I need a chain of patterns (`word1 + word2`) to be printed out only from a text.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of your input? Are you trying to replicate `grep -o`?

Comment: I have a text "Hello my friends, how are you doing these sunny days?". I search for /how are/ string of fields, it is found and awk prints out the whole sentence with these matched patterns. I don't need that kind of output. I need just these two matched words. So my awk input should be like this "how are"

Comment: Sounds just like `grep -o` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if the pattern is a single word (which you want to print and can't contaion `FS` (input field separator)) why not:

```
awk -v MYPATTERN="INSERT_YOUR_PATTERN" '$0 ~ MYPATTERN { print MYPATTERN }' INPUTFILE
```

If your pattern is a regex:

```
awk -v MYPATTERN="INSERT_YOUR_PATTERN" '$0 ~ MYPATTERN { print gensub(".*(" MYPATTERN ").*","\\1","1",$0) }' INPUTFILE
```

If your pattern must be checked in every single field:

```
awk -v MYPATTERN="INSERT_YOUR_PATTERN" '$0 ~ MYPATTERN { 
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i ~ MYPATTERN) { print "Field " i " in " NR " row matches: " MYPATTERN }
    }
}' INPUTFILE
```

Modify any of the above to your taste.

Answer (score 2):

The fields in awk are represented by $1, $2, etc:

```
$ echo this is a string | awk '{ print $2 }'
is
```

$0 is the whole line, $1 is the first field, $2 is the next field ( or blank ),
$NF is the last field, $( NF - 1 ) is the 2nd to last field, etc.

EDIT (in response to comment).

You could try:

```
awk '/crazy/{ print substr( $0, match( $0, "crazy" ), RLENGTH )}'
```

Comment: I know that) How can I print out the MATCHED pattern ONLY? I have a sentence "Hello, crazy world". I need to find /crazy/ and print ONLY the word "crazy" out, if it was found.

Comment: Is there an awk build-in variable for a "matched pattern", I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

i know you can do this with awk :
an alternative would be :

```
sed -nr "s/.*(PATTERN_TO_MATCH).*/\1/p" file
```

or you can use `grep -o`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
awk '{split("bla1 bla2 bla3",a," "); print a[1], a[2], a[3]}'
```

Comment: No, I need awk to print only the matched "word1". Imagine we have a text, where I need to find a chain of words and print the chain out. I don't need the whole sentence, I need just that particular chain or word.