# search for pattern line by line from the second field and print out the first field corresponding to the line where the pattern was found

Tags: perl, awk, grep, multiple-columns, text-processing

I have the following `0.txt` file below separating content by columns (fields):

```
'Disinfectants', 'Brand A', 'Brand B', 'Brand C'
'brand A', 'below brand C', 'greater than brand B'
'brand B', 'greater than brand D', 'below brand A'
```

I would like to find (from the second column) every time a pattern (say "brand A") occurs, and print out the contents of the first column belonging to the line where this pattern is found.
For both the content of the resulting file is like:

```
Disinfectants
brand B
```

I have seen other similar issues but only printing the column itself where the pattern was found, usually using `grep`.

**EDIT UPDATE**: from @jubilatious1 suggestion
, I found a question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9153113) on the OS as part of my search for a solution.

```
awk '/brand A/{ print substr( $1, RLENGTH )}' 0.txt > 1.txt
```

but my `1.txt` output has been different than expected as it prints only part of the content of the first field (column):

```
'brand
'brand
```

Besides, just using  `awk '/brand A/{ print substr( $1, RLENGTH )}'` I can't specify that the search only works from the second field (column) onwards for each line.

**EDIT UPDATE 1**: maybe just fix the output of `awk '/brand A/{ print substr( $1, RLENGTH )}'` so that correctly printing the contents of the fields in the first column is a first step.

Comment: Have you tried at least something? This seems like an `awk` task, didn't you check the existing answers here at SO? There are plenty where you check for a line matching a pattern and printing the first field.

Comment: I've found rough answers using `grep` but haven't focused on fetching answers using `awk`, I'll try to do that now, just give me a break.

Comment: The first row has 4 columns, while the second and third rows only have three.

Comment: @jubiloso1 yes, only the first row has 4 columns, but exactly in this context I'm looking for a solution. I still haven't found time to search for questions using `awk`, but I will keep trying new efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hackish pipeline:

`cut -d, -f2- 0.txt | grep -ni 'brand a' | sed 's/:.*/p/' | sed -nf-  0.txt | cut -d, -f1`

- Split on commas and omit field 1
- grep for line numbers with 'brand a' (case insensitive)
- turn line numbers into `{linenumber}p` -- a sed command to print that line
- pipe those sed commands to `sed -nf-` ... this will print only when instructed to from stdin ... so you get only the lines you want
- split on commas and print only the first field

Or perl:

`perl -lanF, -e 'print $F[0] if grep /brand a/i, @F[1..$#F]' 0.txt`

- Autosplit into `@F` on commas, and print the first field if 'brand a' (case insensitive) is found in any of the other fields.

Both output this:

```
'Disinfectants'
'brand B'
```

You can strip the single quotes however you'd like, or, you can change the `split` regex for perl autosplit:

`perl -lanF"/[',]+/" -e 'print $F[1] if grep /brand a/i, @F[2..$#F]' brand.txt`

To get this:

```
Disinfectants
brand B
```

... note that once the line starts with a split delimiter, `$F[0]` is an empty string.

Comment: I can't get it to work when the search pattern includes single quotes

Comment: The very last one is going to turn any sequence of single quotes and/or commas into a field separator, so the quotes will disappear.  If you want to search for single quotes, I'd suggest the second perl example (comma separator), and try escaping single quotes with a backslash in the regex that comes after 'grep'

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and clarifications, but i added the `-w` option to your `grep` on the code and double quotes around single quotes around the searched string and it worked

Comment: although `-w` only worked on your first solution, ie, `cut -d, -f2- 0.txt | grep -w -ni "'brand a'" | sed 's/:.*/p/' | sed -nf-  0.txt | cut -d, -f1`

Comment: `grep -w` is going to be equivalent to adding `\b` at either end of the regex.  (For word boundary)

Comment: yes, i also remembered `\b`, i tried `cut -d, -f2- 0.txt | grep -ni 'brand a\b' | sed 's/:.*/p/' | sed -nf-  0.txt | cut -d, -f1` and `perl -lanF, -e 'print $F[0] if grep /brand a\b/i, @F[1..$#F]' 0.txt` and it worked.